# Is every hereditarily unicoherent plane continuum non-separating?

Tags: general-topology, plane-geometry, plane-curves, continuum-theory

Let $X$ be a connected compact subset of the plane.  Suppose that $A\cap B$ is connected for every two closed connected subsets $A,B\subseteq X$.  Then is $X$  non-separating?  That is, is $\mathbb R^2\setminus X$ connected?

It seems like the answer should be yes, and I have tried proving it but do not know how.

Comment: The pseudo-circle (not to be confused with the circle of pseudo-arcs) is hereditarily unicoherent, but separates the plane.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.  Take the two endpoint Knaster continuum and identify the two endpoints as shown in the image below:

[2-endpoint Knaster Continuum with Endpoints Identified][1]

The image is from my paper "Atriodic acyclic continua and class(W)" which appeared in Proceedings of the AMS, Vol. 90, No. 3, 1984,  starting on p. 477.

Jim Davis
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N16g3.png